# Unnecessary path present in $PATH

Tags: 14.04, environment-variables

I have configured my `.bashrc` to add paths to the script of certain programs. This is how I did it:

```
export PATH=/opt/android-studio/bin:/opt/pycharm-3.4.1/bin:$PATH
```

However whenever I use `$PATH` in my terminal it shows some additional paths in my Documents directory:

`bash: /opt/android-studio/bin:/opt/pycharm-3.4.1/bin:/opt/android-studio/bin:/opt/pycharm-3.4.1/bin:/opt/android-studio/bin:/home/sanjay/Documents/Programs/pycharm-3.4.1/bin:/home/sanjay/Documents/Programs/pycharm-community-3.4.1/bin:`, plus a few more.

I can't understand why some additional paths are shown up and what should I do to get rid of them.

Answer (score 0):

You seam to have some recursive call into your configuration.

You can "protect" those point or better; the all file thanks to such check:

```
[[ echo "$PATH" | grep -q "/opt/android-studio/bin" ]] || export PATH=/opt/android-studio/bin:$PATH
[[ echo "$PATH" | grep -q "/opt/pycharm-3.4.1/bin" ]] || export PATH=/opt/pycharm-3.4.1/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: I want to get rid of the unnecessary paths that are pointing to some location in the /home/sanjay/Documents/Programs/.... directory, not that in the /opt/.....